# Obfuscation, e.StackTrace unreadable

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I usually obfuscate most of my applications. I'm working on generating error messages that are easier to read so I have been including the StackTrace.

The issue I have with this is that because of the obfuscation programs the StackTrace is unreadable and just contains random characters as it should since all Method names and parameters are unreadable.

What is the best way to handle a situation like this or isn't there one?

Here is an example

[image]

Comment: Can you post an example of the code and output?

Comment: Open up reflector-> Find obfuscated names which you got from stacktrace-> Then go to source to see the original method. That's how I do it :(

Comment: I guess it depends of which Obfuscation tool you use. But mainly, if your method/class names are obfuscated, the StackTrace should be unreadable...

Comment: I don't know what the aim of obfuscation could be that would be compatible with readable stack traces

Comment: It seems that partially unprintable characters are used to rename the methods and classes. Of course this way the stack trace becomes unreadable. The renaming/obfuscation style should be changed to characters which are printable.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never worked with obfuscators myself, my impression is that the obfuscator normally creates a mapping file between the original and obfuscated names that can be used as a dictionary of sorts.

You would have to make (or find) some program that can take an obfuscated stacktrace and the mapping file and translate it back into something readable. Either that or doing it manually.

Unfortunately, obfuscation by its very nature makes debugging more complicated.

Comment: I guess not all obfuscators do that.

Comment: I suppose that's true, in which case code obfuscated by those tools would at best be extremely difficult to debug.